# A condition for a session

Tags: php, session

I am doing a signup page, but I have a small problem
I have an initialize.php page that contains the connection to the DB and a session to check if member is signing in (for all pages)

initialize.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="memoire"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if (!$_SESSION['member_id'])
{
header('Location: login.php');
exit;   
}
?>
```

The problem is inside the signup page, I need a way that inside the signup page (where obviously the member does not have an id) to ignore the "if (!$_SESSION['member_id'])"... I just need the initialize page (inside the signup.php) to only connect to DB.

Comment: why you not use the isset function, isset($_SESSION['member_id']) ?

Answer (score 2):

try something like that :

```
if (!$_SESSION['member_id'] && 
    strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "signup.php") === false){

  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;

}
```

Comment: no problem, please mark my answer as resolved if everything's ok